# Add "---Select" as first item in Combobox in windows form?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework-4

```
var query = (from c in db.tblGroups
             select new { c.GroupId, c.Name })
            .ToList();

GroupcomboBox.DataSource = query;
GroupcomboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
GroupcomboBox.ValueMember = "GroupId";
```

I am Binding my Combobox as Above, I need to add ---Select--- as first combobox item. Please suggest me with Code.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you're asking. What's the problem? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i guess OP wants ... the fist item of Combobox to be `---Select---`

Comment: when i click the combobox the first item in combobox should be like ---select--- by default.how i will manage it

Comment: Exactly Tun Zarni Kyaw i want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add it manually. Beware of your **"Select ----"**     `ValueMember`

```
var query = (from c in db.tblGroups
             select new
             { c.GroupId,
                c.Name
             })
             .ToList();

GroupcomboBox.Items.Add("Select ----");
foreach (var item in query)
{
    GroupcomboBox.Items.Add(item);
}

GroupcomboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
GroupcomboBox.ValueMember = "GroupId";
```

Comment: U did Well Vland but if we do like this we can't access the value Member, it always gives value member 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox` class in C# has properties called `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`.

Take a look at the MSDN library entry [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`---Select---` can be added by `GroupcomboBox.Items.Add()` method
the combobox data needs to be populated with for loop

```
var query = (from c in db.tblGroups
select new
{
    c.GroupId,
    c.Name
}).ToList();
GroupcomboBox.Items.Clear();
GroupcomboBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
GroupcomboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
GroupcomboBox.Items.Add(new {Text="---Select---", Value=-1});
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
{
    string n = stuff.ElementAt(i).Name;
    string i = stuff.ElementAt(i).GroupId;
    GroupcomboBox.Items.Add(new {Text=n, Value=i});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this was asked a very long time ago, I hope my solution would solve someone problems.

```
dt.Rows.Add(-1, "--SELECT--");
```